# nginx & php-fpm in docker: can't finx index.php

Tags: php, docker, nginx

Trying to get `nginx` to use `php-fpm` via `fastcgi` with `docker` compose.
The `php-fpm` container git pulls the code inside the container into /var/www/code/.
When I comment out the `"root /var/www/code"` directive from `nginx's site.conf` file,it's looking into `/etc/nginx/html/index.php`:

```
web_1         | 2018/04/06 14:59:04 [error] 7#7: *1 "/etc/nginx/html/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0:8080"
web_1         | 172.19.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2018:14:59:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "curl/7.47.0"
```

Is this expected behavior? Do I need the app's code to be in the `nginx` container as well in `var/www/code`? Isn't it possible to only use the `php-fpm` container for this purpose, and not have to store the app's code in the `nginx` container as well?

nginx's site.conf:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/code;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php-worker:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
```

From the host:

```
# curl 0.0.0.0:8080
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.13.9</center>
</body>
</html>
```

From docker logs web_1:

```
web_1         | 2018/04/06 14:54:37 [error] 7#7: *5 "/var/www/code/public/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0:8080"
web_1         | 172.19.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2018:14:54:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "curl/7.47.0"
```

docker-comnpose.yaml:

```
version: '2'

services:
    web:
        build:
          context: ./web
        ports:
            - "8080:8000"
        volumes:
            - ./web/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
        networks:
            - redis-cluster
    php-worker:
      build:
        context: ./php-worker
      ports:
            - 9000:9000
      volumes:
            - ./php-worker/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
      networks:
        redis-cluster:
#          ipv4_address: 172.18.0.10
    db:
      build:
        context: ./db
networks:
    redis-cluster:
      ipam:
        driver: host
        config:
          - subnet: 172.18.0.0/24
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

md create /var/www/code folder in your nginx container?
But i think its bad idea to proxy all to php. Better use nginx for all static, and dynamic for php-fpm

Comment: i mean if you don't want code in nginx container, u should proxy all request to php container

Comment: Tried to proxy all reqs to php-fpm container, by removing "root /var/www/code" from nginx config. Instead of proxying to php-fpm container, nginx is trying to fetch index.php from a local directory: `web_1         | 2018/04/06 14:59:04 [error] 7#7: *1 "/etc/nginx/html/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0:8080"
web_1         | 172.19.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2018:14:59:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "curl/7.47.0"`

Comment: try default.conf Instead of site.conf and change listen 8000 to `listen 8000 default_server;` for testing.

Comment: and try localhost:8080/your-script.php coz u have rule in nginx only for php request

Comment: After some trial & error I managed to get it working. I'll post the full config below. Thanks, @Bogdan.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the nginx config which worked in my case:

```
server {
    listen       8000 default_server;
    server_name  localhost;
    root   /var/www/code;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        index  index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }


    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   php-worker:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```